# Microsoft Graph: upload files to onedrive from URL [C#]

Tags: c#, url, upload, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

is it possible to upload files to Onedrive (with Microsoft Graph) from an URL?
If so, please can you give me a code snippet or tell me, how to create the request?

Or have i to download the files first and then upload it from local drive to Onedrive?

Thanks in advance!

Max

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph API does not currently support uploading from a URL. You have to download the file locally first, and then upload it.

If you are targeting OneDrive Personal (not Business), then you can still use the OneDrive REST API to upload from URL:
https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_url.htm